# Http post request to php script

Tags: java, php, apache, http, post

I have a java program which makes an http post request to a php script on my website. Here is the code. I am also using the new Apache HTTP Components API. Here is a link to the download -> http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
{
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://ftstoo.com/public_html/TheFinalTouchSecurity/Database/test.php");

List<BasicNameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Cannon"));


httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);

HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

// Get the HTTP Status Code
int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

// Get the contents of the response
InputStream in = resEntity.getContent();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        out.append(line);
    }
    System.out.println(out.toString());   //Prints the string content read  from input stream
    reader.close();
}
```

}

My test.php file is located at http://ftstoo.com/public_html/TheFinalTouchSecurity/Database/test.php

Here is my php code.

```
 <?php  
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo "Success, . $name . !";
 ?>
```

The output I am getting when I run the java program is the html from a redirecting page on my website that says the page does not exist. I want the output to return a string that says "Success, Cannon!" I think there are probably several things I am doing wrong, but if someone could please give me a hand I would really appreciate it!

Comment: The file doesn't exist, your link goes to a 404.

Comment: I get an HTTP/404 error trying to access that URL - can you access it from your browser? The `public_html` in your path looks very odd.

Comment: Check your server configuration. Looks like its not configured to load the file from your DIR

Comment: I have given permissions for the file to be executed, read, etc for any user. Is that what you are talking about? @Deepak

Comment: @Deepak I am also using cpanel with shared hosting.

Comment: @KenY-n No, I cannot

Comment: If you are using a cpanel then you should be able to load the site without `public_html` in the URL. Im pretty sure this issue is something to do with your server/domain configuration